# How to change Host HTTP Header to break through SNI?

Tags: ssl, curl, openssl, sni

To reach a target file, I must put specific Host Header in request, because server is using SNI.

My server's ip is `172.1.1.61` and `mydomain.com` is target host which can give me a file.

I tried to use a *curl* like that with no success:

```
curl -I --resolve mydomain.com:443:172.1.1.61 https://172.1.1.61:443/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml -v

* Added mydomain.com:443:172.1.1.61 to DNS cache
* About to connect() to 172.1.1.61 port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 172.1.1.61...
* Connected to 172.1.1.61 (172.1.1.61) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* NSS error -5961 (PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR)
* TCP connection reset by peer
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) TCP connection reset by peer
```

Also I tried to use an *openssl client*:

```
openssl s_client -connect 172.1.1.61:443 -servername mydomain.com
```

And it has showed me a valid certificate, related to mydomain.com:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=3 C = US, O = "The Go Daddy Group, Inc.", OU = Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority
verify return:1
depth=2 C = US, ST = Arizona, L = Scottsdale, O = "GoDaddy.com, Inc.", CN = Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, ST = Arizona, L = Scottsdale, O = "GoDaddy.com, Inc.", OU = http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/, CN = Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
verify return:1
depth=0 OU = Domain Control Validated, CN = mydomain.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=mydomain.com
   i:/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository//CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
 1 s:/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository//CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
   i:/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./CN=Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2
 2 s:/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./CN=Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2
   i:/C=US/O=The Go Daddy Group, Inc./OU=Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
LmdvZGFkZHkuY29tL3JlcG9zaXRvcnkvMTMwMQYDVQQDEypHbyBEYWRkeSBTZWN1
some moar strings
cmUgQ2VydGlmaWNhdGUgQXV0aG9yaXR5IC0gRzIwHhcNMTkwNDAzMDQyODE3Wh==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=mydomain.com
issuer=/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository//CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 4609 bytes and written 438 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Session-ID: 9B020000BE0E627BF16F61C924ED4B90FF698F1868168A0467E0F359F98DE1FA
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: (hidden)
    Key-Arg   : None
    Krb5 Principal: None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    Start Time: 1602236714
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
read:errno=104
```

But the last string is `read:errno=104` what is equal to Connection Reset error.

As my last hope I'd installed a Modify Header Value plugin on my Chrome browser and made settings like that:
[image: plugin settings]

But still no connection:
[image]

What I did wrong?

Comment: Both SNI and Host: should be and normally are the hostname (not address) in the URL. Use `curl https://hostname/blah --resolve hostname:443:IPaddr` so it _connects_ to the address but _sends_ the name. Your `openssl s_client` actually connected okay (because it lets you set SNI differently with `-servername` and you did); the reset came _after_ the handshake, likely because after connecting you did not send a valid HTTP request as the server wants.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I tried `curl -o test2 https://mydomainlocal:443/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml --resolve mydomain.com:443:172.1.1.61 -v` but had the same `PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR`

Comment: The name in `https://` should be the _same_ as the one in `--resolve` and should be valid; `mydomainlocal` cannot be a valid name on the public net (and this address is on the public net though I can't reach it)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 this is not a public net. "The name in https:// should be the same as the one in --resolve" - why? SNI can cover several different hostnames.

Comment: The address you gave is public; using it privately is a violation of standards and also a bad idea that usually leads to problems. No, according to standards SNI is exactly the one and only hostname from the URL. (When OpenSSL lets you make it different, that's a violation.) Are you thinking of _SAN_? SAN is in the _certificate_ (not the hello) and can and very often does specify multiple entries, wildcard(s), or both; that's completely different. But `--resolve` is not related to _either_ SNI _or_ SAN; it basically replaces DNS.

Comment: On testing I see curl-with-NSS doesn't give any useful protocol info (only the cert, which is useless here). Can you get curl-with-OpenSSL on your system, or on another system nearby in the same network? If so use that with `-v` to confirm where in the protocol the reset is happening. Otherwise try to get a network capture.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> openssl s_client -connect 172.1.1.61:443 -servername mydomain.com
> ...
> SSL-Session:
>     Protocol  : TLSv1.2
>     Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
> ```
>
> ...
> But the last string is read:errno=104 what is equal to Connection Reset error.

The error you see here means that the connection reset happens in the final stages or directly after the TLS handshake. In this stage SNI is already used to select the certificate and the HTTP request with the Host header is not yet sent. This means that neither SNI nor the Host header are the actual problem here.

This means one can exclude wrong SNI and Host header as the possible reasons for the connection reset. A shared cipher is also found so this is also not a problem. It might be for example a missing client certificate or something else. Maybe the server logs will show.

Comment: Unlikely. `s_client` outputs that message _either_ if server doesn't request client-auth, _or_ requests it with an empty CA list. For OpenSSL 1.0.2 up, which is now widespread though maybe not universal, if server does request auth, `s_client` using 1.2 or lower outputs a line about `Client Certificate Types:` and for 1.2 or higher (only 1.1.1 does higher namely 1.3) two lines about `[Shared] Requested Signature Algorithms:`, neither of which are in OP's post.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: you are right. I've changed the answer to narrow down at least where the problem might be and where not.

Comment: `curl (35)` means curl thinks it was during the handshake. We don't really know it's second flight; the server _could_ send ServerHello before choosing the cert and then fail. It _could_ send the cert but fail on ServerKX because the hello from curl+NSS resulted in a different curve for ECDHE, or even old-non-EC DHE (FFDHE). We need to try to get protocol status, and I commented (on the Q) for that.